# Need CoreData model design advice

Tags: core-data

I have three types of images - regular, favorite and trashed. So I've created three entities in CoreData model designer. I could create inheritance, but regular images are cleared all the time, and if 2 other types inherit from it, they are cleared too, and this is invalid behavior for me (obviously). At the same time these models are very similar. What I want is that they have common parent which contains methods for downloading and saving them in cache. How can I achive this in CoreData?

Answer (score -1):

I've figured it out. You can create any inheritance hierarchy with your classes (root object must inherit NSManagedObject). Inheritance of entities is another topic here. Just set entity name to desired class name and this entity will store data for that class. Simple and smart behavior! F.e. you have class `A` with properties `a1` and `a2` and method `foo`. And class `B` with `b1` and `b2`. You want to store them in different tables, but want to `B` inherit `A` to have `a1` and `a2` and be able to call `foo`. You create class `A : NSManagedObject` with mentioned properties and method, then `B : A` with dynamic properties `b1` and `b2`. That's all your code. Now create 2 models: `A` with `a1` and `a2` attributes and `B` with `a1`, `a2`, `b1` and `b2` attributes. NO entity inheritance `B` from `A` needed here. If you will not add `a1` and `a2` attributes to `B` entity, these properties will be visible in your code, but raise runtime "not recognized selector" exception. Hope this will help some newbie in CoreData.